# How to change the appearance of items in Recycle view based on fragment?

Tags: android

Sorry for the confusing title, I basically have an XML file used for the **RecycleView** item. And now I have 2 fragments, I want the appearance of the item to change based on the fragment I included.

Comment: you can pass boolean in adapter constructor based on from where it is being called. and use that value to check which fragment called your adapter.

Comment: cut this to answer so i can upvote for you.

Comment: it fine, Try implementing this in your code and post it as self answer with code that resolves it. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it

I add 1 more **field** name

> private String **result**

to help this adapter recognized what fragments include, the code I compare the fragment is in the constructor of  "**TicketHistoryViewHolder**".

```
public class TicketHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TicketHistoryAdapter.TicketHistoryViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private String result;
private TicketHistoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener;
private final String TAG = "SAM";

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(int position);
}

public TicketHistoryAdapter(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener, String result) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.result = result;
}

public TicketHistoryAdapter() {}
@NonNull
@Override
public TicketHistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull 
ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

//default view is view name "after confirm"
View finalView=R.layout.item_ticket_after_confirm;

//compare view name by using field "result"
if(result=="beforeConfirm"){
View finalView=R.layout.item_ticket_before_confirm;
  }
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(finalView, viewGroup, false);
    return new TicketHistoryAdapter.TicketHistoryViewHolder(view);
  }
     }
```